Exceção usando entrada decimal para variáveis Double em Java com Scanner
Estou acostumado a sempre utilizar o "." como separador decimal, acredito que esse seja o padrão para todas as linguagens, a menos que o desenvolvedor mude esse separador. Dependendo do programa que eu esteja desenvolvendo, costumo utilizar:
DecimalFormatSymbols virgula = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", virgula);

Após isso era só chamar o método format() do DecimalFormat e assim consigo imprimir o valor de algum resultado usando o vírgula.
Mas o curioso é que, mesmo sem utilizar essa conversão, eu não estou conseguindo sequer utilizar o "." como separador decimal padrão para fazer uma atribuição. Minhas entradas aceitam apenas ",".
Criei essa classe apenas para testar esse trecho e isolar o problema:
package cdl.mobile;

import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class Teste2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.println("altura:"); 
double alt = sc.nextDouble(); // digito 1.80
System.out.println(alt);
    }
}

Pois bem, aparentemente tudo certo, mas ao colocar essa entrada tenho a seguinte exceção:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at cdl.mobile.Teste2.main(Teste2.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1

Se eu coloco a mesma entrada mas usando "," como separador decimal o código funciona perfeitamente e eu sinceramente não faço a menor ideia do que houve para isso acontecer. Já testei em outra máquina minha o mesmo projeto e o erro persiste, também já tentei criar um novo projeto e copiar o código, porém sem sucesso.
Note que não estou definindo nenhum Locale para esse teste. Gostaria apenas de saber o porquê disso acontecer, pois não me lembro de ter esse tipo de problema anteriormente com Java.

Se vc não define nenhum Locale, ele vai usar o default que está configurado na JVM. Se antes funcionava com ponto, é porque o locale default era um no qual o ponto é o separador decimal. Se agora só funciona com a vírgula, é porque está com outro locale configurado. Vc pode fazer System.out.println(Locale.getDefault()); (ou no seu caso, System.out.println(sc.locale());) para ver qual é. Aliás, o mesmo acontece com DecimalFormatSymbols: dependendo do locale default, vai imprimir com vírgula ou ponto.

Enfim, se precisa que sempre seja um separador decimal específico, é melhor setar o locale, assim vc não depende da configuração da JVM. Por exemplo, new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US) para sempre usar o ponto, ou new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(new Locale("pt", "BR")); para usar a vírgula. Ou então vc configura o Java para sempre rodar com o mesmo locale, assim pode usar o default sem se preocupar

Realmente fiz o teste e o padrão está configurado para pt_BR, mas em momento algum fiz essa alteração. Existe alguma explicação para essa mudança ter ocorrido sem o meu conhecimento? Geralmente só instalo o JDK e começo a estudar meus projetos, nunca mudo nada nas suas configurações internas por medo de fazer alguma burrada.

Se não me engano, a JVM se baseia nas configurações de idioma do sistema operacional. Por isso, se vc quer um comportamento específico, não dá pra depender do default.

Sim, eu também já li algo sobre ela pegar as configurações do sistema. Mas o estranho é que sempre utilizei o meu SO em pt-br e me lembro bem de estar usando os separadores padrões no estilo americano para ler uma entrada numérica de decimais. Talvez houve algum update no JDK 17 que uso, mas não sei se funciona assim. De qualquer forma, vou me atentar a isso, aprendi a função do Locale recentemente e vou passar a aplicar mais vezes nos meus projetos para garantir um bom funcionamento. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, amigo!
